# SignalR scaleout client to server broadcast

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-backplane

Using SignalR scaleout how can I broadcast the message from client to all the servers attached to my backplane? I thought it should work by default, however only one server's hub is receiving the message.

Setup: I have 4 virtual machines behind the load balancer and I am using SignalR with Redis backplane. I have the following Hub:

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    public void StartProcessing(string clientId)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And on the client side, I am invoking this method with:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
    proghub.server.startProcessing(me.clientId);
});
```

I've enabled tracing on the Message bus and the message is received on all the servers:

```
SignalR.ScaleoutMessageBus Information: 0 : OnReceived(0, 54, 1)
```

However, the Hub method is invoked on only one server. How can I make this call execute the StartProcessing method on all servers?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. The best way is to enable some kind of synchronization mechanism between servers. Since Redis is used as a backplane it can be also used as such mechanism.